# How to stop android from restoring state when the app process is killed?

Tags: android

I'm facing an issue with the way android handles the launch of an activity after the app process has been killed.
It tries to restore the activity with some previously collected data but that makes my app to crash (I did some research and found out that the usage of `?attr:themeAttr` in the xml layouts was the reason)

I don't want android to restore anything after a process kill, is there a way to disable it ?

Note: The same activity launches when clicking different keys, and the data shown are different too, based on the keys.

Say,

- The activity was launched by pressing key '1', and minimized
- Android kills my process
- The user presses key '2' to launch the same activity

In the above scenario, the activity needs to show fresh data based on the key '2'. So, android trying to restore the state of the activity before the process was killed (key '1' data) is unnatural for my case

How to address this ?

Answer (score 0):

When starting the activity, try adding the flag "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK" to the intent.